# How to return the smaller of an OR operator regex when both are present?

Tags: python, regex

This regex:

```
    import re
    string = 'I am a long string with many regexes matching'
    pattern = '.*(?:with|regexes)'
    print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

returns

```
['I am a long string with many regexes']
```

How can I instead make it return:

```
['I am a long string with']
```

i.e. when both the short and long version of the regex is present, return the shorter string.

Comment: Yep, that solved my problem. Thanks